# Travis CI doesn't show public repository?

Tags: travis-ci

I have a publc repo that *should* be visible in Travis CI, but it isn't.

I have googled and found [this](https://travis-ci.community/t/github-repo-doesnt-appear-in-travis/4263/2) thread.

I have

- Pressed the 'Sync account' button a few times (it says last synced a minute ago, so it seems to think it has worked)
- [These](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/migrate/open-source-repository-migration#the-migration-steps) steps indicate there should be four tabs: Repositories, Settings, Subscription, Migrate, but I only see the first two (critically, no 'Migrate' tab)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, hope this helps someone else, but signing out of Travis and back in (via github) solved it - the missing repo appeared.

Comment: Fixed it for me as well. Thank you!